# Regular expression tester

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

There are 6 lines of input. The first line will contain 10 character strings. The last 5 lines will contain a valid regular expression string.
For the output, each regular expression print all the character strings that are matches to the strings according to line 1; if none match then print `none`.
`#` is used to represent a empty string

Example Input:

```
1)#,aac,acc,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb 
2)a.c 
3)a[ab]c 
4)a[^ab]c 
5)ab*c 
6)ab{2,4}c
```

Example Output:

```
1)aac, acc, abc 
2)aac, abc
3)acc 
4)ac,abc,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc 
5)abbc,abbc,abbbbc
```

Why is this code not working:

```
import re
inp = input("Search String:").upper().split()
for runs in range(5):
    temp = []
    query = input("Search Query:").replace("*", ".*").replace("?", "[A-Z0-9]+?+$").upper()
    for item in inp:
        search = re.search(query, item)
        if search: # means match
            temp.append(item)
    if len(temp) > 0:
        print(" ".join(temp))
    else:
        print("No Match")
```

Comment: Please add further details to question, not as comment and maybe you can clarify where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: okay thank you i did, i added it to the question

Comment: beacuse i am new to regular expressions and i just started using them so i watned help understanding them better with python and have not been able to get my code to do what i want

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing?

Comment: the problem is that i can not get regular expressions in python to work like i want it to i want it to work with that input data and it does not it outputs some items that are correct but then also prints incorrect outputs

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Your question doesn't include a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: it is not a homework problem you can see i had a previous question but then a user asked me to reword it " 
Please add further details to question, not as comment and maybe you can clarify where exactly you're stuck." so i just made it into a exact problem lol but yeah if you look at what Anmol Singh Jaggi did i wanted it to be something like that the only problem with that one is it prints out duplicates of the same output

Answer (score 1):

I think you are conflating regexes with globs, which suggests that you aren't so much of a regex beginner as you let on. That said, here's some code that shows the differences between glob and regex styles.

```
import re

EXAMPLE_INPUT = """
1)#,aac,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb,ab4c
2)a.c
3)a[ab]c
4)a[^ab]c
5)ab*c
6)ab{2,4}c
"""

lines = [x[2:] for x in map(str.strip, EXAMPLE_INPUT.strip().split('\n'))]
search_strings = [ l if l != '#' else '' for l in lines[0].split(',')]
patterns = lines[1:]

for pat in patterns:
    glob = pat.replace('.', r'\.').replace('*', r'.*').replace('?', r'.')
    # should also do:  .replace('[^', '[!') but you used ^ everywhere
    glob = re.sub(r'{([^}]*)}', lambda m: '(' + m.group(1).replace(',', '|') + ')', glob)
    for ss in search_strings:
        if re.search(pat, ss):
            print("Regex '{}' matches '{}'".format(pat, ss))
        if re.search(glob, ss):
            print("Glob '{}' matches '{}'".format(pat, ss))
```

Output is:

```
Regex 'a.c' matches 'aac'
Regex 'a.c' matches 'abc'
Regex 'a.c' matches 'aabc'
Regex 'a.c' matches 'accb'
Regex 'a[ab]c' matches 'aac'
Glob 'a[ab]c' matches 'aac'
Regex 'a[ab]c' matches 'abc'
Glob 'a[ab]c' matches 'abc'
Regex 'a[ab]c' matches 'aabc'
Glob 'a[ab]c' matches 'aabc'
Regex 'a[^ab]c' matches 'accb'
Glob 'a[^ab]c' matches 'accb'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'aac'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'abc'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'abc'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'ac'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'abbc'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'abbc'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'abbbc'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'abbbc'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'abbbbc'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'abbbbc'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'aabc'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'aabc'
Regex 'ab*c' matches 'accb'
Glob 'ab*c' matches 'ab4c'
Regex 'ab{2,4}c' matches 'abbc'
Regex 'ab{2,4}c' matches 'abbbc'
Regex 'ab{2,4}c' matches 'abbbbc'
Glob 'ab{2,4}c' matches 'ab4c'
```

Comment: i wanted it to  be like generic so did u see how i had like a input so they could input there sting and have it so it worked with any input

Comment: Sure, but I'm working with your examples, not generic user input. Feel free to put that back in.

Comment: yeah, do you know how you would make it generic because i looked at your code and do not see where you would put it

Comment: and i wanted to make it like output like 1. aac acc abc and i get like you found all the matches but how would i match the matches together if that makes any sense lol

Comment: First, replace the `search_strings =` with a read from the user. Then change `for pat in patterns` to be a loop that reads the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write `,` as an argument to `split()`.

Also, while matching the full string, comparing whether `search` is `None` or not is not enough. This is so because `re.search()` finds the pattern throughout the text, which means it will find all the **substrings** of the text matching the pattern (I am assuming you want only the substring starting from the beginning to match).

To remedy this, we can use `re.match()` instead of `re.search()`.

```
import re

inp = input("Search String:").upper().split(',')

for runs in range(5):
    temp = []
    query = input("Search Query:").replace("*", ".*").replace("?", "[A-Z0-9]+?+$").upper()
    for item in inp:
        search = re.match(query, item)
        if search:
            if search.group() not in temp:
                temp.append(search.group())
    if len(temp) > 0:
        print(" ".join(temp))
    else:
        print("No Match")
```

Comment: that almost works i tried it with input 2 and 4 and for input 4 it creates no match when it should output acc whys that

Comment: but thank you for helping me so far

Comment: @JoeGreen Check it now!

Comment: it works but then prints acc twice is there any way to fix that and it means a lot all of all the help you have been so far

Comment: so wouldnt there just have to be something that would find the doubles and delete the double

Comment: Ummm, one `acc` is in the first output and the second one is in the third output, right?

Comment: `Search Query:a.c
AAC ACC ABC ACC` is there any way we can get it to just be `aac acc abc`

Comment: `Search Query:a[^ab]c
ACC ACC` so like there is there any way to just print 1 `acc` also and thank you so much i can not explain how thankful i am for you helping me would i could pay you if you wanted you've been so much help so far but if we can fix this its all good so do you know if you could fix that problem :)

Comment: It's strange because when I run, `ACC` is getting printed only once. See [this](http://ideone.com/V0JbyQ)

Comment: and i think i found the problem i might have typed the wrong input on the webpage here it is once again #,aac,acc,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb @anmol-singh-jaggi

Comment: @JoeGreen Check it now

Comment: with ab*c it outputs `Search Query:ab*c
ABC ABBC ABBBC ABBBBC` could it output `ac,abc,abc,abbbc,abbbc` @anmol-singh-jaggi and i am sorry if i am taking up your time this means a lot

Comment: because on mine that one was the only one now that messed up

Comment: I don't get it; `ab*c` doesn't match `ac`, then why do you want it in the output? And, why do you want duplicates; you just told me you didn't want them.

Comment: * matches the preceding character zero or more times and the output i would want would be ac,abc,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc

Comment: `SAMPLE INPUT:1)#,aac,acc,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb` `2)a.c` `3)a[ab]c ` `4)a[^ab]` `5)ab*c` ` 6)ab{2,4}c` Sample Output `1)aac,acc,abc` `2)aac,abc``3)acc``4)ac,abc,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc` `5)abbc,abbbc,abbbbc

Comment: Yeah, but you are yourself converting the pattern from `ab*c` to `ab.*c` using this line - `query = input("Search Query:").replace("*", ".*")`.

Comment: Okay i removed that and i think it fixed it

Comment: @JoeGreen Phew! That took some effort, eh? Could you please upvote this answer too?

Comment: why does b* not work

Comment: i have a question how would i get b* to work and show #